# Solve integral equation (running of the strong coupling)

Tags: numerical-methods, integral-equations

I have the following equation
\begin{equation}
    \int_{a_s(\mu_1)}^{a_s(\mu_2)} \frac{d  a_s}{\beta(a_s)} = \ln \left(\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}\right),
\end{equation}
with $\beta$ being expanded with known coefficients $(\beta_1 - \beta_4)$
\begin{equation}
\beta(a_s) = \beta_1 a_s^2 + \beta_2 a_s^3 + \beta_3 a_s^4 + \beta_4 a_s^5.
\end{equation}

With a given $a_s(\mu_1), \mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ I now want to calculate $a_s(\mu_2)$ numerically. I have to implement this in a C++ code, so I cannot use Mathematica.

What are the names of the numerical methods I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

First re-write the relation as a differential equation by differentiating both sides with respect to $\mu_2$.  I found,
$$
\mu_2 \frac{\partial a_s(\mu_2)}{\partial \mu_2}  = -\beta(a_s(\mu_2)) \Rightarrow \mu \frac{\partial a_s}{\partial \mu}  = -\beta(a_s) 
$$
Solving a differential equation using a large number of small steps $\delta\mu$ is a basic technique in most numerics textbooks.  The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) should help you start but a trip to the library might be best.  I like [Kreyszig, Advanced Engineering Mathematics](https://www.amazon.de/Advanced-Engineering-Mathematics-Erwin-Kreyszig/dp/0471728977/ref=dp_ob_image_bk).  The initial condition is $a_s(\mu_1)$ and you will be able to evaluate the $\beta$-function using its expansion.